# Obtain separate data from json file with php

Tags: php, json

I've been seeing multiple ways to count the clicks on a file download link.
The option that has been viable so far is to use a json file, to store the data; However I have the problem to be able to extract the data individually, since I need to display the data according to the current page, which has a unique ID.

This is the first time I am working with json files, and it has been complicated so far, I hope I can help.

**HTML Data:**

```
<a class="MxDownload" data-nameplugin="File-<?php the_ID(); ?>" href="<?php echo $file_down; ?>" title="<?php echo __('Download the ', 'cyberdocentes'); ?><?php the_title(); ?>" download><?php echo __('Download the ', 'cyberdocentes'); ?><?php the_title(); ?></a>
```

**JSON data File (is a external file):**

```
{"File-262":{"countDownloads":4},"File-260":{"countDownloads":2}}
```

**This is my php code:**

```
<?php
global $down_id;
    $data = file_get_contents (''. get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/scripts/dataDownloads.json');
        $json = json_decode($data, true);
        $down_id = 'File-'. get_the_ID() .''; //This is unique ID for the URL

        foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
            if (!is_array($value)) {
                echo '<pre>' . $val . '</pre>';
            } else {
                foreach ($value as $key => $val) {
                    $count_down = $json[$down_id]['countDownloads'][0][$val];
                    echo "Descargas: ". $val ."<br />";
                }
            }
        }

?>
```

**The Print Data is:**

```
Descargas: 4
Descargas: 2
```

I want to get only data related to the ID of the current link.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in foreach loop you should do like

```
foreach($json as $key=>$value)
{
     // check whether your $key is similar to your fileid
     if($key==$down_id)
     {
        if(is_array($value))
        {
            // now your $val holds the download numbers
            foreach ($value as $key => $val) {
                    echo "Descargas: ". $val ."<br />";
                }
        }
     }
   }
```

Comment: let me know whether it works for you or not ... if worked please accept as correct answer